# Design question about Activity model / table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have got an activity model which keeps track of each users activity. In this model I've got the following columns: id, user_id, media_id, type, created_at, updated_at

One activity I am particularly concerned about is the song view. For example. When a user clicks on a song, the song starts playing. At the same time this happens, my app creates an activity for this, each time the user views the song page.

This means I could keep a sort of history time-line for user activities. i.e.

```
Foobar listened to Song A 2 hours ago
Foobar listened to Song A yesterday
Foobar listened to Song B 2 days ago
etc
```

In the future, if the app/site gains a lot of popularity, will this in some ways affect the database performance? I am worried that this table will populate itself very fast just for each user that views a song. I can't help looking at the videos on youtube which has around 100k ++ views per video.

Should I be worried? Or is it all about adding indexes and making sure the db can scale in terms of memory and disk space?

Answer (score 1):

I think the activity model does too much since you also store data, that is never needed.

```
      table
------------------------
user_id        int
media_id       int
listened_at    TIMESTAMP
```

I'm omitting the type since this should be in context of `media_id`

If you realy get many hits per view, a simple database would not be able to handle this. Even a devent database cluster *might* have problems with that. But I would not actually worry about these things at an early stage.

Comment: The reason why I have a type field in there. Is because type can be View, Like, Comment, etc. The purpose of the activity model is to store all types of user interactions. If you believe the activity model is doing too much, what do you suggest? :-)